# Run ChromeOS emulator on Apple silicon

Tags: android-emulator, google-chrome-os, apple-silicon

I'm trying to test my app through ChromeOS emulators on MBP M1 laptop. But the available emulators are either 32bit or 64bit and they crash on launch. I've followed [this doc](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/chrome-os-android-studio/) for adding the emulator images. Is there any workaround or any other ChromeOS emulator that can be used?

[image: Error message]